# Sorting array of object

Tags: javascript

I developed E-commerce app.

I have a list of products.

Here is my array:

```
[
   {
        Desc:Commodo adipisicing officia non excepteur officia nostrud,
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Commodo adipisicing officia non excepteur officia nostrud. Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 161.0,
        }
   },
   {
        Desc:Laborum cupidatat dolor tempor cillum incididunt,
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Laborum cupidatat dolor tempor cillum incididunt in veniam nisi dolore.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 80.0,
        }
   },
   {
        Desc:Anim ad et sunt aliquip proident,
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Anim ad et sunt aliquip proident fugiat deserunt.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 150.0,
        }
   },
   {
        Desc:Eiusmod aliquip eu aute elit eiusmod proident,
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Eiusmod aliquip eu aute elit eiusmod proident.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 130.0,
        }
   }
]
```

I need to sort based on `PRICE_SALE`.

```
Low to High and high to low.
```

I tried this:

```
var a=this.product.sort(function(a, b){
                  console.log("SORT");
                  return a.details.PRICE_SALE-b.details.PRICE_SALE;
                })
```

But it's not work.

Comment: *But it's not work* In what way? Run-time error? Unexpected results? By the way, the values of the `Desc` property should be quoted.

Comment: You should look into this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.No i don't get error msg.But Does not display the order.I need sort to Low to High and high to low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your array element to object:

```
var arr = [
   {
        "Desc" : "Commodo adipisicing officia non excepteur officia nostrud",
        "details" :{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Commodo adipisicing officia non excepteur officia nostrud. Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 161.0,
        }
   },
   {
        "Desc": "Laborum cupidatat dolor tempor cillum incididunt",
        "details":{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Laborum cupidatat dolor tempor cillum incididunt in veniam nisi dolore.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 80.0,
        }
   },
   {
        "Desc" : "Anim ad et sunt aliquip proident",
        "details":{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Anim ad et sunt aliquip proident fugiat deserunt.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 150.0,
        }
   },
   {
        "Desc":"Eiusmod aliquip eu aute elit eiusmod proident",
        "details":{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Eiusmod aliquip eu aute elit eiusmod proident.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 130.0,
        }
   }
];
```

See the result:

```
var a = arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.details.PRICE_SALE - b.details.PRICE_SALE;
})

a.forEach(function(ele) {
    console.log(ele.details.PRICE_SALE); // 80, 130, 150, 161
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the quoting problem on `Desc` your code works fine. Note that the `sort()` method sorts the array *in place*. It also returns the sorted array, but don't let that fool you into thinking that it makes a copy of the array and sorts that (e.g. `.sort()` does not work like `array.slice()` which copies an array in full or part and returns the copy).

```js
var products = [
   {
        Desc:"Commodo adipisicing officia non excepteur officia nostrud",
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Commodo adipisicing officia non excepteur officia nostrud. Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 161.0,
        }
   },
   {
        Desc:"Laborum cupidatat dolor tempor cillum incididunt",
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Laborum cupidatat dolor tempor cillum incididunt in veniam nisi dolore.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 80.0,
        }
   },
   {
        Desc:"Anim ad et sunt aliquip proident",
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Anim ad et sunt aliquip proident fugiat deserunt.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 150.0,
        }
   },
   {
        Desc:"Eiusmod aliquip eu aute elit eiusmod proident",
        details:{
            "P_TITLE" : "Martina",
            "P_TYPE" : "simple",
            "P_DESCRIPTION" : "Eiusmod aliquip eu aute elit eiusmod proident.Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
            "P_STOCK" : 100.0,
            "PRICE_REGULAR" : 194.0,
            "PRICE_SALE" : 130.0,
        }
   }
];

products.sort( function( a, b ) {
 return a.details.PRICE_SALE - b.details.PRICE_SALE;
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( products, null, 4 ) );
```